# set values from application properties to classes with interface

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

I have application.yml file with properties:

```
animals:
  tiger:
    name: "Joe"
  lion:
    name: "Simba"
```

I created classes for that properties (AnimalProperties.Class, Tiger.class and simillar Lion.class):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "animals")
@Getter
public class AnimalProperties {

    Animal tiger = new Tiger();
    Animal lion = new Lion();
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class Tiger implements Animal{
    public static final int ID = 1;
    String name;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

And interface for these classes:

```
public interface Animal {
    String getName();
    int getId();
}
```

There is also class for returning a correct animal depends of its ID:

```
public class AnimalChooser {
    
    public Animal getById(int id) {
        AnimalProperties animalProperties = new AnimalProperties();
        if(id == Tiger.ID) {
            return animalProperties.getTiger();
        } else {
            return animalProperties.getLion();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that during testing AnimalChooser name of the animal is **null**.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AnimalProperties.class)    
class AnimalChooserTest {
        AnimalChooser animalChooser = new AnimalChooser();
    
        @Test
        void shouldReturnCorrectNameForTiger() {
            Animal tiger = animalChooser.getById(1);
            assertEquals("Joe", tiger.getName());
        }
    }
```

I don't know what is missing here so I would be grateful for some help with it.
And one more thing - mapping from application.yaml to java classes works well. I tested it with such test:

```
class AnimalPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    AnimalProperties animalProperties;

    @Test
    void shouldProperlyReadTheBusinessPropertiesYamlConfigFile2() {
        Animal tiger = animalProperties.getTiger();
        Animal lion = animalProperties.getLion();
        assertEquals("Joe", tiger.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Animal` should be a class with the field `String name` and `Tiger` with `Lion` should extend the class. The interface would not work.

Comment: It didn't help, name is still null

Comment: Ok, I have a solution for it and it works with the interface. The problem was that I didn't @Autowire AnimalProperties in AnimalChooser class but I create a new instance of that class directly. Seems that spring need to Autowire to read a application.yml properly.